# Why is the number of singularities (zeros and poles) of an elliptic function finite in a fundamental domain of a lattice in C?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ spanned by $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

1. Denote $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ = $\{a\omega_1 + b\omega_2~|~a,b \in [0,1)\}$.  Why is $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ compact?
2. Suppose $f$ is an elliptic function in $\Gamma$. Why is the number of poles $mod ~\Gamma$ of $f$ finite? (Elliptic function refers to the doubly periodic meromorphic functions.)
3. Let $n_z(f)$ and $n_p(f)$ denote the numbers of zeros and poles of $f$ respectively in $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$. Why is $n_z(f)$ = $n_p(f)$?

Comment: Isn't this covered in every text on elliptic functions. See for example ch1 of Apostol's book on Modular forms and Dirichlet series. Anyway, some hints: 1) $\Bbb{C}/\Gamma$ is a continuous image of a closed parallelogram. 2) an infinite subset of a compact set has an accumulation point. 3) by part 2 there is a translate of a lattice parallelogram not touching any of the poles or zeros, what happens if you integrate $f$ along the perimeter of such a parallelogram? Use periodicity!

Comment: $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ : for every $a$ there is some $k$ such that $f(z) (z-a)^k$ is analytic around $a$, so $a$ can't be an accumulation point of zeros or poles, so $f$ has finitely many zeros and poles on any compact and hence on any parallelogram.